# AmazonS3.readObject() very slow from AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading a 1.5 MB file located in S3 from an AWS lambda:

```
public class AwsFileStorage {

    private static final AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    static {
        var builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
        builder.setRegion(MY_REGION);
        amazonS3 = builder.build();
    }

    public InputStream read(String filekey) {
        var initTime = Instant.now(); // Timer ON
        var s3Object = amazonS3.getObject("bucket-name", filekey);    
        var endTime = Instant.now();  // Timer OFF

        var millis = Duration.between(initTime, endTime).toMillis(); 
        System.out.println(millis);

        return s3Object.getObjectContent();
    }
}
```

When I run this code on a 512 MB AWS lambda (in the same region of my S3) directly from the AWS console, I got:

> 3642 millis

But when I run the same code, also fetching the file from the AWS S3:

> 486 millis

I don't understand, how is possible that the execution of `AmazonS3.getObject()` could run x10 faster from my laptop than from a lambda executed over an AWS infrastructure, even when the file is as well hosted in the same AWS infrastructure - same region.

Any reason for this delay?
Is there any other more optimal way to read a file hosted in S3 from a AWS lambda?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you measure the time? It may include its initial provisioning, in which case it will be slow. Subsequent executions are usually faster as lambda reuses its execution context?

Comment: i agree with @marcin  .. Probably run it in a loop of 10..ideally only first should take time while other 9 shuld be super fast. .. and then see average time.. pls do post results for my learning also.

Comment: @Marcin you could see in the code how I measure the time. I am measuring only the required time for calling amazonS3.object(). I don't think the provisioning time affect here. Also be aware that my AmazonS3 client is static, so when this line of code run, the client was already loaded.

Comment: Then can try with more ram. 512 MB will give you only 0.28 vCPU. If you want power of 1 vCPU then need 1792 MB of ram.

Comment: @Marcin Good point! with 1792 MB this line runs in over 1sc, x3 faster. I didn't know this RAM/CPU relation in lambdas. So the bottleneck here is the CPU, I don't think the RAM would be a problem, cos until I'd consume the s3Object.getObjectContent() InputStream the content of the file is not properly fetched.

Comment: Definitely, the delay comes from low vCPU, because the max consumed RAM of my lambda is only 185 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Technically even though its hosted publicly remember that it must traverse the public internet to reach S3 which is located in the AWS Public Zone for that region.

You could migrate your [Lambda to be located inside your VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/), and add a [VPC Gateway Endpoint for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html).

Additionally can you confirm this is average Lambda request time and not just the first request? If so that could be cold start

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the memory and cpu allocation you are provisioning when you run the process on your laptop. That may be way higher than 512 mb